# excel vba runtime error 1004; i don't have select in the code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy some inputs to a model and copy back the answers to the first sheet. Below is the code. "data_sheet" is the sheet with many inputs and "Final Model" gives the out put. Its very simple; i am trying to copy data from 
"data_sheet" to "final model" and then copy the answer back. I am getting error 1004 when i try to copy back answer to "data_sheet". the first part alone works good.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range
    Dim rngStart2 As Range, rngSource2 As Range, rngDest2 As Range

For i = 1 To 6

    Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data_sheet")
    Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final Model")

    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range(Cells(5, 3 + i - 1), Cells(23, 3 + i - 1))
    'Paste Data Values
    Set rngDest = wksDest.Range("C14")
    rngSource.Copy
    rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


'Till this code works. Now i just trying to reverse copy

    Set rngSource2 = wksDest.Range(Cells(38, 4), Cells(40, 4))
    Set rngDest2 = wksSource.Range(Cells(29, 3 + i - 1), Cells(31, 3 + i - 1))
    rngSource2.Copy
    rngDest2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is because you're trying to define a range on `wksDest` using `Cells` from the *Active* worksheet, which will always fail unless `wksDest` is active. So this statement:

```
Set rngSource2 = wksDest.Range(Cells(38, 4), Cells(40, 4))
```

Actually says this:

```
Set rngSource2 = wksDest.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(38, 4), ActiveSheet.Cells(40, 4))
```

And since a range can't be defined on one sheet using cells on a different sheet (without taking other extraordinary measures), to avoid that, you can use `With` block like so:

```
With wksDest
    Set rngSource2 = .Range(.Cells(38, 4), .Cells(40, 4))
End With
With wksSource
    Set rngDest2 = .Range(.Cells(29, 3 + i - 1), .Cells(31, 3 + i - 1))
End With
```

Or a more direct approach using `Resize` method:

```
Set rngSource2 = wksDest.Cells(38,4).Resize(3)
Set rngDest2 = wksSource.Cells(29, 3 + i - 1).Resize(3)
```

Both above approaches avoid the unqualified `Cells` object which is a likely cause of 1004 error.

Also, since you're only copying values, you can do simple value assignment instead of `copy` and `pastespecial`, like so:

```
rngDest2.Value = rngSource2.Value
```

Comment: pay attention to the `.Cells` -- you need to use the `.` to explicitly qualify to the sheet -- but I'd prefer the second approach 